Is there any way to share MS SQL Server connection between multiple k8 pods? (using pyhton)
Context: I am implementing a RabbitMQ consumer, connecting to database with pymssql and SQLAlchemy. The connection is made using a username and password. I need to deploy multiple pods of this consumer, but when I tried to run two applications simultaneously locally, one of them raised the error below, which made me understand that it is not possible to connect using the same login simultaneously.
I know that the best way to solve this would be by changing the database configurations, but it is not that easy to change in my case, due to internal company reasons. Therefore, I am looking for a temporary, faster solution because I have a short deadline too...
Given this, I would like to know if there is any way to first establish and then share the connection between pods, and if this could actually help me solve my problem. Something like obtaining a token from the MSSQL connection and then sharing it via Redis.
Error:
Error in execute query: (pymssql.exceptions.OperationalError) (18456, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (SRV-DBHMG)\n')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
[2024-05-15 11:00:07,467] * INFO * in (METHOD) update_job_in_db : Job status updated    
[2024-05-15 11:00:07,467] * ERROR * in (METHOD) handle_cotista_jcot_integration : Error: Não foi possível atualizar esse cotista - erro: (pymssql.exceptions.OperationalError) (18456, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is 
unavailable or does not exist (SRV-DBHMG)\n')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)```


it is not possible no, it is. Otherwise web apps like StackOverflow itself wouldn't work. SO is an ASP.NET Core application connecting to SQL Server.

First of all, pymssql is NOT the recommended driver. It has several quirks and one of them is mentioning Sybase's Adaptive Server product. Yes, SQL Server originated from Sybase in the very early 1990s but has nothing in common since the late 1990s. More important quirks have to do with missing features. The recommended way is pyodbc using Microsoft's own far faster and more powerful ODBC driver

On the other hand, Unable to connect: means that specific client can't even find the server, much less login. That's a networking issue. Either the SQL Server pod doesn't export the correct port or the client doesn't connect to the correct service or port. Or maybe the two pods can't see each other at all

Which, btw, means this question is borderline out-of-scope, for lack of information. At the very least post the K8s configuration

You shouldn't share database connection, just create separate connections or even better processes that connects separately. Most databases since the 70s support multiple users logged on at the same time, including sql server

Thanks, @PanagiotisKanavos, for the clarifications; it actually makes sense. Regarding the topic, at one time my main doubt was whether it is possible to share the connection or not; I chose this one. Indeed, I have not even tested it in K8s, just locally, running two different applications consuming the same queue. Having this issue, I know that it probably won't work in K8s either. But yes, I think this could be - borderline - relevant to the K8s topic as well.

@siggemannen Yes, I know, but I cant have the same user logged from many applications, right? I think that was the point of  Panagiotis

Database connections have nothing to do with queues. If you can't connect to a database server on the same or remote machine something is wrong with the code, or the network connection. I have a short deadline too... in that case don't experiment and go through the step by step proof of concept tutorials. Create a single Python file and get pyodbc.connect(connectionString) to work

@YuriSilva I cant have the same user logged from many applications, right? wrong. The database doesn't care about applications, only connections. It doesn't care where the connections come from. All server-based database products work the same. I repeat, if you're in a hurry, go through the tutorials to verify what's really true so to speak.

To see that multiple applications can connect at the same time, all you have to do is create a single Python file that connects to the database and waits or better yet, runs queries in a loop, and run it from two different terminals. Database servers are built to handle hundreds of concurrent connections.

@PanagiotisKanavos, you were right again. The issue I was having wasn't about a login failure but rather a temporary unavailability of the database itself. After it was resolved, I can now run as many applications as I want, making queries with the same users. I will update this issue soon to avoid confusion.

In that case check the Idle Connection resiliency feature which can handle transient failures like those happening on a local-to-cloud connection.
